# CSS, not sure how to move things around

Tags: html, list, subscribe, mailing

[image: the problem]

I'm trying to remove the message box and I want to move the e-mail box to the right of the name, so that it all fits into the top bar.

I have tried removing the message box through the html code, but when I do, I get errors and it doesn't function properly.

I assume I have to remove something in the PHP because it's obviously not able to find the missing html code, but as I don't understand PHP I don't know what to remove.

this is the html code for the subscribe button

```
  <div class="subscribe">
     <div class="containerContact">
        <div id="contactFormContainer">
           <div id="contactForm">
              <div class="loader"></div>
              <div class="bar"></div>
              <form action="mail.php" class="contactForm" name="cform" method="post">

                 <div class="input_boxes">

                    <p><label for="name">Name</label><span class="name-missing">Please enter your name</span><br />
                       <input id="name" type="text" value="" name="name" />
                    </p>

                    <p>
                       <label for="e-mail">E-mail</label><span class="email-missing">Please enter a valid e-mail</span><br />
                       <input id="e-mail" type="text" value="" name="email" />
                    </p>

                    <p><label for="message">Message</label><span class="message-missing">Say something!</span><br />
                       <textarea id="message" rows="" cols="" name="message"></textarea>
                    </p>

                 </div>
                 <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" onfocus="this.blur()" />

              </form>
           </div>
           <div class="contact"></div>
        </div>
     </div>

     <!-- this is the overlay which hides the rest of the website when the Subscribe button is pressed. -->
     <div id="backgroundPopup"></div>

  </div>
```

I can't post more than one link, so here is a text dump to the [PHP and CSS for the subscribe button](http://dumptext.com/fO0jnC5R)

any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: If you want a subscribe to mailing list option, you will have to store the email addresses somewhere, like a database. Simply write the email to the database, and when you want to send a mass-email, you grab all the email addresses, and do something like a while loop, to send them to every person. Maybe consider using a table to put the message box besides the text, or use separate div's ?

Comment: Removing the message box in html shouldn't give you any errors at all... I'm pretty sure it's at the php level. Please post php code

Comment: The php code can be found in the link in the post, it's the last link on the post. When I remove some of the html code it doesn't work properly, in terms of the way it sends and automatically closes